# How to add copyright symbol in pyLaTeX?

Tags: python, pylatex

I'd like to use the copyright symbol in [PyLaTeX](https://jeltef.github.io/PyLaTeX/). I tried using `"\textcopyright"` but the `\t` is being interpreted as a tab, resulting in a `.tex` file which contains only `extcopyright`. Is there a way to get the copyright symbol properly?

```
    from pylatex import Document, PageStyle, Head, MiniPage, Foot, LargeText, \
        MediumText, LineBreak, simple_page_number
    from pylatex.utils import bold 


    def generate_header():
       geometry_options = {"margin" : "0.7in"}
       doc = Document(geometry_options=geometry_options)

       header = PageStyle("header")

       with header.create(Head("L")):
           header.append(bold("institute \textcopyright"))

       with header.create(Head("R")):
         header.append(bold("TEST"))

       with header.create(Foot("L")):
         header.append(bold("institute"))

       with header.create(Foot("C")):
         header.append(bold(simple_page_number()))

       with header.create(Foot("R")):
         header.append(bold("Document")) 

       doc.preamble.append(header)
       doc.change_document_style("header")


       doc.append("Test")


       doc.generate_pdf("header", clean_tex=False)

    generate_header()
```

Comment: Maybe write `"\\textcopyright"` or `r"\textcopyright"`? I don't know, this works for me when working in [manim](https://github.com/3b1b/manim), which is based on Python 3.7. A [Minimal Working Example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) would help to determine your issue. Also, welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: The comment from @GregorPerčič seems to be spot-on, and this question is probably only a Python question. I'm voting to close it.

Comment: @GregorPerčič I had tried both of the suggestions you had mentioned but it did not work. I have included the minimal working example in the question.

Comment: @praphult Then I don't know how to help you. The only syntax between LaTeX and Python I experienced was thorough manim. Otherwise, I have no clue, sorry. Tip: check your Python version? Maybe my syntax only works for Python 3.7. Note that you will get a precise answer much quicker on a more Python-oriented Stack Exchange site, such as Stack Overflow, which is deducated to resolving questions about programming. God bless and keep you always.

Comment: You need `header.append(bold("institute \\textcopyright", escape=False))` to stop the bold command expanding the backslash(es).

Comment: @AndrewSwann Thank you. Your suggestion solved my issue. GregorPerčič, Thanks for the time. It works on both versions of python. Thanks to Andrew Swann.